# Fail validation if there is a peroid (.) not in the specific format?

Tags: c#, regex, fluentvalidation

I'm scanning a string and a period is allowed but if there is a period it has to be in the following format `alphanumber.numeric` or `numeric.numeric`. Here are some possible acceptable formats:

> 5555.1312
> ajfdkd.555

Here is what i have so far:

```
private const string containsPeroidRegularExpress = @"([a-zA-Z]+\.[0-9]+)|([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)";; 
 
  validator.RuleFor(x => x.myString)
      .Matches(containsPeroidRegularExpress)
      .When(x => x.myString.Contains("."), ApplyConditionTo.CurrentValidator)
```

When you have an example like this it works fine:

> This is my example 1 555.1212

But in this example it does not

> This is my example 2 555.1212   .

You can see the extra period at the end of the 2nd example. It should fail validation because the extra peroid is not in the specified format stated above. The 1st example should pass validation. Both pass the validation though.

Comment: How about `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?$`

Comment: This site is useful for testing purposes: https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern is still capturing exactly what you want, however it doesn't "know" that it needs to keep going.

```
private const string containsPeroidRegularExpress = 
    @"^([a-zA-Z]+\.[0-9]+)$|^([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)$";
```

The `$` tells it to check right up until the end of the line (I also added `^` to tell it to start at the beginning for completeness so that ". 555.1212" doesn't pass as well).

I definitely won't say this is the best solution. As others mention, you can definitely simplify it. However regex isn't my forte...

I also noticed you mention that the pattern could be `alphanumber.numeric`. Your pattern does not allow both alpha and numeric characters mixed in the first part. You could use the following:

```
private const string containsPeroidRegularExpress = 
    @"^([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[0-9]+)$|^([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)$";
```

Answer (score 0):

You might check that after matching the value, there is no space followed by a dot on the right.

You can shorten the pattern a bit by either matching 1+ digits or 1 chars a-zA-Z, and then match a dot and 1+ digits

```
(?<!\.[^\S\r\n]+)\b[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[0-9]+\b(?![^\S\r\n]+\.)
```

The pattern matches

- `(?<!` Negative lookbehind, assert what is on the left is not

  - `\.[^\S\r\n]+` Match a dot and 1+ whitespace chars without a newline
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `\b` Word boundary
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[a-zA-Z]+|[0-9]+` Match either 1+ chars a-zA-Z or 1+ digits
- `)` Close group
- `\.[0-9]+` Match a dot and 1+ digits 0-9
- `\b` Word boundary
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert that on the right is not

  - `[^\S\r\n]+\.` Match 1+ whitespaces without newlines followed by a dot
- `)`  Close lookahead

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5c.%5b%5e%5cS%5cr%5cn%5d%2b%29%5cb%5ba-zA-Z0-9%5d%2b%5c.%5b0-9%5d%2b%5cb%28%3f!%5b%5e%5cS%5cr%5cn%5d%2b%5c.%29&i=5555.1312%0d%0aajfdkd.555%0d%0a1+555.1212%0d%0a2+555.1212+.%0d%0a%0d%0a113+Pine+St.+115.5555)

If you want to match mixed char a-zA-Z and digits:

```
(?<!\.[^\S\r\n]+)\b[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[0-9]+\b(?![^\S\r\n]+\.)
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5c.%5b%5e%5cS%5cr%5cn%5d%2b%29%5cb%5ba-zA-Z0-9%5d%2b%5c.%5b0-9%5d%2b%5cb%28%3f!%5b%5e%5cS%5cr%5cn%5d%2b%5c.%29&i=5555.1312%0d%0aajfdkd.555%0d%0a1+555.1212%0d%0a2+555.1212+.%0d%0a%0d%0a113+Pine+St.+115.5555)

Comment: thanks that was close but the following example didn't work "113 Pine St. 115.5555" which should fail because of "St."

Comment: @coding4fun You might do it like this and check for not a dot and space before `(?<!\.[^\S\r\n]+)\b[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[0-9]+\b(?![^\S\r\n]+\.)` https://regex101.com/r/4c9Cqf/1